# JAX-RPC Web Services WSDL2Java

Tags: web-services, wsdl2java, jax-rpc

I'm having a problem with JAX-RPC wsdl2java technology.
My wsdl2java ant task:

```
    <wscompile
            fork="true"
            server="true"
            client="false"
            base="${build.main.generated.jaxrpc.dir}"
            config="${src.main.config.dir}/jaxrpc-service-config.xml"
            keep="true"
            features="">
        <classpath refid="jaxrpc.classpath"/>
    </wscompile>
```

When I run this task wscompile does not include JAXRPCServlet in web.xml.

```
<servlet-class>com.sun.xml.rpc.server.http.JAXRPCServlet</servlet-class>
```

and when deploy web service the endpoint is not available. JAX-RPC config file looks as follows:

```
<configuration xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-rpc/ri/config">

<wsdl location="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/wsdl-jaxrpc/MyWsdl.wsdl" packageName="my.package.name">
    <namespaceMappingRegistry>
        <!-- Name space mappings -->
    </namespaceMappingRegistry>
</wsdl>
```

Maybe I'm missing something or my ant task is bad?